# ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x0000000e490b98 in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a application using ruby on rails, but currently i'm suffering a problem like db relation, below my code:

Company

```
has_many :posts, :foreign_key => :company_id
```

Post

```
belongs_to :companies, :foreign_key => :company_id
```

controller

```
@post = current_user.companies.all
```

view

```
<% @post.each do |p| %>
  <%= p.posts.post_title %>
<% end %>
```

Showing error above code.

If I `debug` like use `<%= debug p.posts %>` then showing all posts, which is under my `companies` but when I use `<%= debug p.posts.post_title %>` then showing `ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x0000000e490b98`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you are trying to call the method `:post_title` on `p.posts`, which is an `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` object.

In your example, `p` is a `Company` object, which has a method `posts`, which returns to you a `CollectionProxy` object that acts a lot like a list of posts. That list will not have a method `post_title`, but each element of that list will have a method `post_title`

So, instead of

```
<% @post.each do |p| %>
  <%= p.posts.post_title %>
<% end %>
```

You will want something like:

```
<% @post.each do |company| %>
  <% company.posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= post.post_title %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

---

Two additional things to note:

1) The variable `@post` is inaccurately named. Inaccurate variable names will lead to confusion when trying to understand what is happening.  `current_user.companies.all` returns a list of companies, and therefore, it should read:

```
@companies = current_user.companies.all
```

not

```
@post = current_user.companies.all
```

2) The actual error that is being shown to you likely says something like

```
Undefined Method 'post_title' for ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x0000000e490b98
```

Not just

```
ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x0000000e490b98
```

When debugging and asking for help, it's very important to note the entire message of the exception being raised.

Comment: You are so Brilliant :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because companiy has_many :posts........ posts are objects you need a loop to show all posts e.g 
    p.posts.each do |post|